# NativeScript - how to get google maps my location button to show

Tags: angular, google-maps, nativescript

I am building an app with NativeScript 6+ and Angular 8+.

I am using this google maps plugin: https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk

It's working fine but I want to display the 'my location' button. I have it enabled but it's not turning up.

[image]

template

```
<Page class="page">
    <GridLayout rows="auto,*">
        <Label row="0" class="h3" text="Maps"></Label>
        <MapView
            row="1"
            #mapView
            i-padding="50,50,50,50"
            (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
            myLocationButtonEnabled="true"
            myLocationTapped="myLocationTapped()"
            iosOverflowSafeArea="true">
        </MapView>
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

component

```
export class ClockingComponent implements OnInit {
    mapView: MapView;

    constructor() {}

    public ngOnInit() {}

    public onMapReady(event) {
        console.log(" map ready ");

        const mapView = event.object;

        this.mapView = mapView;

    }

    public myLocationTapped() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source in that repo, I was unable to find Angular bindings explicitly created, but I compared the [definition file](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/blob/master/src/map-view.d.ts#L31) to the Angular demo [template](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/blob/master/ng-demo/app/map/map.html#L3). I think you'll have to follow the member variables that exist:

```html
        <MapView
            row="1"
            #mapView
            i-padding="50,50,50,50"
            (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
            [myLocationEnabled]="true"
            (myLocationTapped)="myLocationTapped()"
            iosOverflowSafeArea="true">
        </MapView>
```

You can see from its definition, the `MapView` class has the member variable `myLocationEnabled`, not `myLocationButtonEnabled`, even though the latter is the name used in `UISettings`. Additionally, don't forget that output bindings need parentheses around them `(myLocationTapped)`.

Comment: It seems so, myLocationButtonEnabled does not have any effect in the code I am testing. After requesting permissions (I use nativescript-geolocation) I have: this.mapView.myLocationEnabled = true; (the button to point to your location appears)

Comment: i am facing the same problem right now and can't find solution. any idea?